# Directory API Scope

Tags: google-admin-sdk

i used a sample code of OAuth2 access using clientid for native application.  I sent in a scope for the following:

"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user"

But for some reason, i'm not presented with the acceptance for the end user.  If i sent in this, i do get the consent message popup in the browser.

"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.orgunit"

Can you tell me what i'm missing here?

Comment: can you show your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work actually. I was found that there was security under user account that i needed to revoke so new one can be accepted.